# How addition works for local and static variables in C and assembly

Tags: c, variables, memory, assembly, addition

This code was compiled with gcc 5.3.1.

Assembly instructions were generated through gdb 7.11 using `disassemble main`

The operating system is GNU/Linux running on an x86_64 processor.

---

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    return ++i;
}

push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
pop    %rbp
retq
```

---

```
int main() {
    static int i;
    return ++i;
}

push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
mov    0x200b54(%rip),%eax
add    $0x1,%eax
mov    %eax,0x200b4b(%rip)
mov    0x200b45(%rip),%eax
pop    %rbp
retq
```

---

In the first example the memory address is being operated on directly, whereas in the latter case the value must first be transferred to the `eax`register. Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Well, static variables are not handled in the same way as local variables. They have to be stored in a specific portion of process memory. The compiler cannot optimize them away, or at least doesn't try to hence the extra load.

Comment: Ah okay. For some reason I thought all operations involving the ALU had to be done through a register. @Bakuriu

Comment: The static storage class instructs the compiler to keep a local variable in existence during the life-time of the program instead of creating and destroying it each time it comes into and goes out of scope.

Comment: Your first version will probably do just nothing when optimized, just return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on is that you didn't tell gcc to optimize the assembly. Thus, what assembly it emits is not really representative of what the CPU can do. In optimized assembly, the two sequences would probably look like this:

```
# adding 1 an automatic variable in register eax
add $1,%eax

# alternatively
inc %eax

# adding 1 to an automatic variable on the stack
add $1,12(%rbp)

# alternatively
inc 12(%rbp)

# adding 1 to a static variable
add $1,i(%rip)

# alternatively
inc i(%rip)
```

`rip` is the instruction pointer. On amd64, access to static variables is typically done relative to the instruction pointer to enable PIC code.